# Best copper wire for solenoid

Tags: solenoid

I am going to make a solenoid that will only be required to lift a small metal rod for a couple of seconds - and not very often.

It has to run of a standard 9V battery and the small rod should be as big as possible. So - which wire gauge should I use to get the most lift? I am getting 100 grams of lacquered copper wire but can choose the gauge - from 0,15 to 2,00 mm. thick.

So longer but thin wire with a lot of turns or thicker but short wire with few turns?

Edit to clarify:
This is for a sort of puzzlebox.
The 9V is not my choice - that is what it has to be.
Different people will come and open it - each will have a "new" battery with them - so how long it will last is of no interest for me - as long as it can open the lock for a few seconds.
The small rod should be as big as possible because it is a lock - but I am aware that a 9V will probably not lift anything too big - therefore "small". I therefore do not have the measurements of it as I will chose it based on the solenoids capability.
I have next to no knowledge of the calculations regarding this project - it is pretty much trial and error. I just need to know which gauge will probably give me the best chances ;-)

Edited to further clarify:
When I write "as big as possible" I am not really looking for the max - I am looking for something long enough to penetrate the sides of the box sufficiently to be secure and something thick enough to not just snap if forced.
The rod will probably penetrate about 5-7 mm. and will have to be moved that distance.
The box is to commemorate the 200 year of the first lecture proving electromagnetism. This is also the reason that I want it as simple as possible with as few parts as possible as it will be made of plexiglass so that the opener can see that it is only electromagnetism doing the work. This is also why I want gravity to work as the locking-mechanism and the rod has to be lifted.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Are you aware of Ohm’s law? Can you check the datasheet for your battery what current capability it has? “As big as possible” is a difficult engineering term. Can you narrow it down?

Comment: The small rod should  be as big a possible?  Any actual desired measurements?

Comment: You need to calculate the force required to lift the rod. From \$ F = ma \$ you get \$ F = mg \$ if the force you're fighting is gravity. From there you can start to calculate your solenoid. [Edit] the details into your question.

Comment: Choose how long you want the battery to last, then choose the wire that has resistance that will make it last that long. (probably you want the thinnst)

Comment: @Jasen That completely disregards whether the current and ampere-turns will be sufficient to do the work required.

Comment: no, it maximises it, whuich was the request.

Comment: Standard 9V battery is the wrong starting point for this. It's bad at supplying teh sort of current a solenoid needs. You't be better with a single cell ... ideally a D cell but even an AA or two is better than the little 9V ones.

Comment: @Jasen I'm not sure where you read that. The OP specifically asks how to get the most **lift** (magnetic strength); not most battery life.

Comment: Related: [What is the max current from a 9 V battery?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/503936/2028)

Comment: just use a 12V electric strike and a boost converter.(to make 12V from 9V) or disasswemble the strke and rewind the solenoid (fold the wire in half and wind it back on for 6V operation)

Comment: _"The small rod should be as big as possible because it is a lock"_ - why is a rod smaller than 'as big as possible' not acceptable? How far does the rod need to move? Why does it need to be 'lifted'? Why does the 'lifter' have to be a solenoid?

Answer (score 1):

The limiting factor here will be the amount of current the 9V battery can source. This may be between 500mA and 1A, if you're using a typical alkaline type. ([Energizer 9V datasheet](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/max-eu-9v.pdf))

Making electromagnets requires balancing voltage, current, wire gauge, and number of turns (total length of wire). For example, if you use a small length of reasonably large gauge wire (negligible resistance), the circuit will try to draw more current than the battery can supply, causing it to get hot and its lifetime severely shortened.

If you use a very fine gauge with many turns, there might be so little current that despite having many turns, the electromagnet is too weak for your application.

Start with the maximum current as a starting point. Since you are only engaging it for a few seconds, perhaps 500mA will work. If you use 32 AWG wire, which has a resistance of about 164Ω per ~300 meters, then you can determine the length of wire needed to draw that amount of current.

What resistance is needed for 500mA?

$$
R = E/I \\
R = 9V / 0.5A\\
R = 18Ω
$$

If 300 meters is 164Ω, then we can determine the fraction of that length that would be 18Ω:

$$
18 / 164 = 0.109\\
0.109 \times 300m = ~33m
$$

So you would need to wrap 33 meters of 32 AWG wire to have a resistance that draws 500mA.

But here is the complication: If you choose a thicker wire, the resistance will go down, making the current go up. But you'll also have a shorter wire, and fewer turns. So the goal is to optimize the number of ampere-turns: You want the highest current *and* a high number of turns.

Also of great importance here is the core diameter and material. The diameter will affect how many turns. My experience is that using a low carbon steel rod (more iron) -- [something with high magnetic permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)#Values_for_some_common_materials) -- will provide greater magnetic strength.

Because there are so many variables, I found utility in reading Rick Hoadley's [Experiments with Electromagnets](http://www.coolmagnetman.com/magelect.htm) page. There is a link to [a spreadsheet](http://www.coolmagnetman.com/coildata.xls) that allows you to enter core radius, wire gauge, coil length, and applied voltage to see the resulting number of turns, current, etc.

Although 9 volts can produce greater current with a given amount of resistance, a 9V *battery* can't provide as much current as 1.5V cells (AA, C, D), as Brian Drummond mentioned in comments. (This is because a 9V battery is made up of six quite small 1.5V cells that cannot source much current.)

Use the spreadsheet to experiment with different values for wire gauge and voltage. The **gauss** values will give you the resulting calculated field strength. To determine whether a given field strength is sufficient to lift the metal rod is beyond my knowledge; suffice to say, you might be building a few electromagnets before you succeed.

Comment: good breakdown of a very complex subject.